# JSON.parse returning invalid Array or Obj - debugger reports conflicting information

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, json

A verbose explanation provided for clarity.  It pains me to write a question on **anything** JSON-related, as I feel it's so tried and true I must be missing something.  Regardless, this one is still troublesome.

First, the offending code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
parent.iframeContentLoaded.promise.then(function prepareExistingContacts() {
    var jsonString = '<?php echo json_encode($subjectContacts); ?>',
        existingContacts;
    console.log('JSON string as echoed by php: ' + jsonString);
    var existingContacts = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    console.dir(existingContacts);
    return existingContacts;
})
</script>
```

I json_encode an object in php, and echo it on screen for so I can debug it.
The output appears to be valid JSON, as tested via:

1. setting `var x = {..the echo'd JSON..}` in a Chrome console,
2. pasting it into [jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com),
3. a thorough inspection!

All check-out.  However, that JSON gets interpreted *differently* seemingly whether or not I'm using the debugger; AND, chrome outputs a bogus length for the bogus array it has parsed.

Let me show you a screenshot of the code above executed in the console:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLI9T.png

Check out the Array[#]s.  Do you see the discrepancy in the number of properties and bracketed [array length]?  The content is incorrect in them too (well, key "0"'s value is correct, but "1" and "2" are wonky).  I only expect keys "0" and "1", as shown below in the pretty printed JSON.

When I place a 'debugger' or even just a breakpoint into my Chrome console and step through the same, everything is functional--it parses just as expected.  ANARCHY!:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReZ7J.png

Could it be related to the async nature of my promise `.then()`?  Likely not--the string is printed directly into an explicit (local, not global) `var`, and is thus isolated from other processes.  It's unlikely weird characters from `json_encode`--the same issue exists when using `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`, and the whole scenario is repeatable in FireFox.  I am using v35 of Chrome and I believe v29 of FireFox.

Any tips?

**Echo'd JSON**:

> [{"subject_contact_id":2,"firstname":"TestContact2F","lastname":"TestContact2L","addresses":[{"subject_contact_address_id":2,"subject_contact_id":2,"line1":null,"line2":null,"city":null,"state":"AL","postalcode":null,"country":"US","notes":null}],"phones":null},{"subject_contact_id":1,"firstname":"TestContactFName","lastname":"TestContactLName1","addresses":[{"subject_contact_address_id":1,"subject_contact_id":1,"line1":"123 Happy Streety","line2":"apt 4","city":"Cloud City","state":"OR","postalcode":"22222","country":"US","notes":"super noters"}],"phones":[{"subject_contact_phone_id":1,"subject_contact_id":1,"number":1112223333,"extension":12121,"notes":"note love","type":"mobile"}]}]

Comment: Indeed, the output was from json_encode with the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT arg specified.  Updated.

Comment: What you're seeing is Chrome's Developer Tools' ability to show a live representation of objects (arrays, in your case). When you logged the array, it is being referenced. After the code you posted, you must be modifying the array, because something's adding to it (later), and Developer Tools is showing the update. As you noticed, the number in the brackets is the original length when you logged it (correct), while the expanded contents are "live"

Comment: Ian, thank you for the help.  I believe this is indeed the correct issue.  However, I wouldn't go as far to mark it as a duplicate.  The user in the ref'd duplicate case is asking a much more targeted question, while I asked a symptom of the common cause.  Is it not more desirable instead to simply post your content as answer and point to that thread?